# Mocking window.document in JEST and vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, testing, jestjs

I have a problem with mocking `window.document` property in my test. I want to test a simple vuex action, which fetches config with favicon url. Next, favicon is being set. Unfortunately, window.document object in actions file is not replaced by mock function.

actions.js

```
const changeFavicon = (url) => {
    try {
      console.log(window.document.createElement) //always prints [Function: createElement] instead of [Function: mockConstructor]
      let link = window.document.querySelector('link[rel*="icon"]') || window.document.createElement('link');
      link.type = 'image/x-icon';
      link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
      link.href = url;
      window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

...
async fetchConfig({ commit }) {
    const { data: config } = await api.get('config');

    if (config.favicon_url) {
        changeFavicon(config.favicon_url)
    }

    commit('setConfig', config);
    return config
},
```

and actions.spec.js

```
    it('should set favicon', async () => {
        const document = window.document
        Object.defineProperty(global, 'document', {
            value: {
                createElement: jest.fn(),
                addEventListener: jest.fn()
            }
        })

        console.log(global.document.createElement) // printss correctly [Function: mockConstructor]
        expect(global.document.createElement).toHaveBeenCalled()

        Object.defineProperty(window, 'document', { value: document })
    })
```

Regards

Comment: Ok, I solved it. The important thing is to mock it before import file

Comment: You can also add "attachToDocument: true" as a mounting option.

shallowMount(Component, { attachToDocument: true })